# Aspx - position of Gridview PagerSettings

Tags: asp.net, gridview, position, settings, pager

i've create a Gridview in a web page,
i've insert the PagerSettings and i've aligned it to the bottom.

Now it's in the left part of the grid, i wanna put in the right part how i can do?

Comment: Show us your markup and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the pager is rendered as a TABLE inside of the TABLE that the GridView is rendered as, in other words the inner row of the last table row in the grid is what you need to change.

Check out this blog entry for a better explanation and code:

[GridView and Paging Alignment](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Aug/18/GridView-and-Paging-Alignment)